# django model instance in form without model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have a form say:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to pass model instance on it so that when user tries to edit their profile they get their existing data on the form.

For some reasons I am not using `ModelForm`

lets say I have instance `user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)`

and I want to pass instance like form = ProfileEditForm(instance=user)

I googled and found I can only use instance with model form but can I use it in form too that not from model ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give the reasons you are not using ModelForm? You should.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because my supervisor said so. He just want to use form only. Is there anyway I can get this ?

Comment: I don't know what kind of "supervisor" tells you to use the wrong class. To update a model instance, use a ModelForm.

Comment: Thank you. Except model form i cant do it right ?

Comment: You _could_ write a custom constructor for the Form to simulate the modelform, but like Daniel said: just use the right tool for the task, a ModelForm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
user = User.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('first_name','last_name','email','address')
form = ProfileEditForm(user[0])
```